# string conversion to COleDateTime (CRecordset)

Tags: c++, database, datetime, string-conversion

In a CRecordset, i want to store two dates into a database table. The fields on the database are from type `datetime (MS SQL)`.

There are two variables named `validfrom` and `validto` from type string. The `dateformat` from the string-variables are DD.MM.YYYY. `m_Validfrom` and `m_Validto` is from type `COleDateTime`.

At `CFSC_FULLTRUCK::Update()`, i get a conversion error.

`"Invalid character value for cast specification"`

```
void CFSC_FULLTRUCK::setfulltruck(int nr ,CString ort,CString country ,CString  zone, double cost ,CString  file_index, string validfrom, string validto, double fuelinpercent, CString remark)
    {
        CFSC_FULLTRUCK::Open();
        CFSC_FULLTRUCK::AddNew();
        m_NR = nr;  
        m_ORT =ort;
        m_COUNTRY =country;
        m_ZONENO = zone;    
        m_COST = cost;          
        m_FILE_INDEX = file_index;  

        if(validfrom == ""){validfrom = "01.01.2001";}
        if(validto == ""){validto = "31.12.2020";}

        m_Validfrom.ParseDateTime(validfrom);
        m_Validto.ParseDateTime(validto);
        m_Fuelinpercent = fuelinpercent;
        m_Remark = remark;


        CFSC_FULLTRUCK::Update();
        CFSC_FULLTRUCK::Close();
    }
```

Comment: I get the date from an CSV file from customer. The only way is to read the CSV with string and format or convert it to a DateTime.

Comment: ParseDateTime() returns a bool.  Do **not** ignore a false return, something is going to go bang! when you don't have a valid date.